# Why would we declare a 2nd variable in the below code?

Tags: javascript

Why would we declare a second variable (`val`) when we can use the parameter of the function as a variable?

Here's how it looks like on codecademy:

```
var divideByThree = function (number) {
    var val = number / 3;
    console.log(val);
};
divideByThree(6);
```

I've made some changes as below:

```
var divideByThree = function (number) {
    number = number / 3;
    console.log(number);
};
divideByThree(6);
```

And it works pretty fine!!

Comment: Not sure this belongs on slack. FWIW, You are correct. A future lesson will likely introduce the concept of closures though. Patience padawan. :)

Comment: You can, but maybe you need the original value AND the derived value. In this small example, there's no point in having `val`. in some other code, maybe `val` would be `var val = big_long_ugly_heavy_cpu_intensive_call(number)` that you won't want to repeat.

Comment: well, continuing the logic, you can save more space by coding `6/3` or even just `2`...

Comment: Most times I've seen recommendations to not use the parameter is that some people may get confused about the fact that you are not changing the original value of the parameter, but only the copy that gets into the function scope.  I tend to use the parameter in this way in my own code though.

Comment: By the same extension you might as well go on to `number /= 3;`. This sample is too small to carry much actual meaning.

Comment: i think they just meant to spell it out for clarity; js is not like php where you need to assign vars to somethings in order to use it because expressions (including assignments) are leaky in JS.

Comment: Really? I wrote it as  console.log(number/3) and it works pretty fine too!!

Comment: There is nothing unclear about his second function. Using clarity as the reason ignores the actual reasons to use the var token in JS, which is to control scope and even more importantly, autogc and memory leaks. Human readability in code comes from standards and patterns, not var declarations. There is no replacement for excellent code commenting practices, not even verbose var names. If you can't read JS that has Spanish or Russian var names or the like, something else much worse has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you do not need to preserve the original value of the parameter.  However, you may find it easier to use extra variables in the future for more complicated functions.

Here is an example:

```
// This function uses the parameter "rawNumber" as a variable, but also uses an extra variable "number"
function TestThis(rawNumber, p) {
    // Convert the input (string) to integer
    // parseInt returns NaN or integer.  Truncates decimals
    var number = parseInt(rawNumber);

    // Check to see if the result is NaN or is an integer
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        Log(rawNumber + " is not a number.", p); // Log is my imitation of console.log()
    }

    // will run if number is type int
    else {
        if (number > 0 && number <= 100) {
            Log(rawNumber + " is a valid number.", p);
        } else {
            Log(rawNumber + " is not between 1 and 100.", p);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this code working in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/9zjubtcm/4/).

In this function I used an extra variable called "number" in three different places.  I didn't have to, but it was easier than typing `isNaN(parseInt(rawNumber))` and `if(parseInt(rawNumber) > 0 && parseInt(rawNumber) <= 100)`.  Codecademy was probably decided to teach you this way because it is easier to realize you can simplify your code than to realize you can simplify a more complex code through the use of extra variables.

Also, JK Price's answer brings up a readability issue.  Simply put, this code is easier to read and understand:

```
function Example(number) {
    var processedNumber = 5/(Math.log(1/number*3.14 - 7));
    console.log("Message: " + (processedNumber * 2));
    console.log("Message: " + (processedNumber / 10));
}
```

This code might be a little harder:

```
function Example(number) {
    console.log("Message: " + ((5/(Math.log(1/number*3.14 - 7)) * 2));
    console.log("Message: " + ((5/(Math.log(1/number*3.14 - 7)) / 10));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort.. I've got it !! btw, i notice that the function hasn't been called yet.  something like: TestThis(5 ,"overflow");

Comment: I actually used this function in a website.  The function is called when the user puts in a new input (you can see the function call near the bottom of the javascript section in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/9zjubtcm/4/)).  The `p` in `TestThis(rawNumber, p)` is the ID of the paragraph that I want any messages to go to.  `p` gets passed into the `Log(text, p)` function.  The `rawNumber` is whatever you type in the inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Variables are supposed to help the programmer write better and describe a better story. You can't have the same actor play multiple characters! One thing it does is to help keep variables separate.

The variable `val` in this case helps abstract the logic and most importantly help in debugging. If this was a long script and you saw that `number` was not what you originally passed it, you might consider it to be an error.